# CSS3 keyframe animations in Firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I have the following css3 rules

```
#sun, #sun div { 
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:1000px;
    -webkit-border-radius:1000px;
    -moz-border-radius:1000px;
    -ms-border-radius:1000px;
    -o-border-radius:1000px;
    animation:sunrise 3.2s ease 0 infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation:sunrise 3.2s ease 0 infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation:sunrise 3.2s ease 0 infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation:sunrise 3.2s ease 0 infinite alternate;
    -o-animation:sunrise 3.2s ease 0 infinite alternate;
}

@-moz-keyframes sunrise {
   0%  {background:rgba(255,255,204,.23);}
  75% { background:rgba(255,255,204,0.5); } 
  100% { background:''; }
}
```

However, the Firefox implementation doesn't seem to work. 
The background colors are all set in rgba format
but each `#sun` div has a different color.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've posted is very much incomplete, but there are quite a few things that aren't ok.

- You should **always** write the **unprefixed** versions **last**, never before
  the prefixed ones.
- `-ms-border-radius` and `-o-border-radius` ***never existed***! And unless you
  need to support FF3.6, `-moz-border-radius` is useless. `-webkit-border-radius` is pretty much useless these days too - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius
- Firefox 16+ (current version is 19) supports unprefixed keyframe animations! See http://caniuse.com/css-animation
- `0s`, not `0`! Plus the default value for the delay happens to be `0s` anyway so you can omit it and just write `animation: sunrise 3.2s infinite alternate;` (the same way you can omit `ease`, which is the initial value for the timing function)
- `background: rgba(255,255,204,0)`, not `background: ''`!

And a question: why use such a huge `border-radius`? My laptop screen is much smaller than anything that would require such a huge `border-radius`. If you just to make a disc, give your element equal `width` and `height` and set `border-radius: 50%`.

Comment: ok gothca! I was just trying to do a catch all for lower browsers. as for the background being ''; each div has a different  background color...so they all blend to one colour but revert back to each's default colour which differs from each other hence the background:''